# No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:myDBtest

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, derby

I've noticed that there are a lot of people here who already asked same question, so I tried to follow the solutions that people suggested.
However, I'm still struggling with an error below.. Please advise!

"myDB" which is the table I created and already inserted some rows. And it is in my eclipse project folder.

ps. Java and Javac command works so I think the environment setting is set.

code:

```
try {            
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}           

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:myDB");
System.out.println(conn);
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM marathon");
```

and error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:myDB
at                 
java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
at 
java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
at Main.actionPerformed(Main.java:166)
    .
    .
    .
```

Your help would be very appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");` should be ` `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();`  See https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyClientSpec.html

Comment: @PM77-1 That is not correct (and if that is necessary, that would be a severe bug in the driver implementation). The JDBC specification specifies that loading the class should be sufficient to register the driver.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - I was going by all the **examples** I'd seen in "official" tutorials,  I do not know whether it is actually required.

Comment: @PM77-1 It isn't required, the only reason some tutorials show use of `newInstance()` because almost 15-20 years ago, an early version of the MySQL driver had a bug where they registered the driver in an instance initializer instead of in a static initializer as required by the JDBC specification. And people have cargo-culted use of `newInstance()` ever since.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your URL is `jdbc:derby:myDB`, which is the Embedded Derby syntax, you need to have `derby.jar` in your `CLASSPATH`, and then Derby will open the embedded database located in the folder `myDB` relative to the current working directory of your program.

If you really wanted to use the Client/Server version of Derby, with the `ClientDriver` as your JDBC driver, then you need to change your Connection URL syntax to use the client-server syntax, and you need to have the Derby Network Server running.

Here's a tutorial which will help you get started and understand all these concepts: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/getstart/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was trying to figure out where to find and how to add `derby.jar`. However, I resolved the issue as I copied and pasted `derby.jar` in my current working directory, and set the Build Path in Eclipse. Thanks again.